# issue with apostrophes in a function with div.innerHTML

Tags: javascript

This code make an error.
Probably the problem is with location.href apostrophes.

```
div.innerHTML ='<div id="link">\
<input type="button" onclick="location.href='http://www.google.com';"/>\
</div>';
```

Comment: @Pablo No, that's not a dupe. The linked question is about bash, which uses a completely different escape mechanism to JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can escape your string like this:

```
div.innerHTML ='<div id="link">\<input type="button" onclick="location.href=\'http://www.google.com/\';"/>\</div>';
```